# How can i upload images to ipfs correctly

Tags: frontend

I have been trying to create this NFT marketplace but whenever I try to click "create and list nft, my metamask won't get prompted. Then inspected the localhost and it is saying that there is an issue uploading the image to ipfs and I am also not sure if i have to get my own rpc node on infura. Thanks for any help. below is the error and the code for the create.js file which is supposed to create and mint the nft.

localhost
[image: localhost]

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ethers } from "ethers"
import { Row, Form, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { create as ipfsHttpClient } from 'ipfs-http-client'
const client = ipfsHttpClient('https://ipfs.infura.io:5001/api/v0')

const Create = ({ marketplace, nft }) => {
  const [image, setImage] = useState('')
  const [price, setPrice] = useState(null)
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('')
  const uploadToIPFS = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    if (typeof file !== 'undefined') {
      try {
        const result = await client.add(file)
        console.log(result)
        setImage(`https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${result.path}`)
      } catch (error){
        console.log("ipfs image upload error: ", error)
      }
    }
  }
  const createNFT = async () => {
    if (!image || !price || !name || !description) return
    try{
      const result = await client.add(JSON.stringify({image, price, name, description}))
      mintThenList(result)
    } catch(error) {
      console.log("ipfs uri upload error: ", error)
    }
  }
  const mintThenList = async (result) => {
    const uri = `https://ipfs.infura.io/ipfs/${result.path}`
    // mint nft 
    await(await nft.mint(uri)).wait()
    // get tokenId of new nft 
    const id = await nft.tokenCount()
    // approve marketplace to spend nft
    await(await nft.setApprovalForAll(marketplace.address, true)).wait()
    // add nft to marketplace
    const listingPrice = ethers.utils.parseEther(price.toString())
    await(await marketplace.makeItem(nft.address, id, listingPrice)).wait()
  }
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid mt-5">
      <div className="row">
        <main role="main" className="col-lg-12 mx-auto" style={{ maxWidth: '1000px' }}>
          <div className="content mx-auto">
            <Row className="g-4">
              <Form.Control
                type="file"
                required
                name="file"
                onChange={uploadToIPFS}
              />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} size="lg" required type="text" placeholder="Name" />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)} size="lg" required as="textarea" placeholder="Description" />
              <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setPrice(e.target.value)} size="lg" required type="number" placeholder="Price in ETH" />
              <div className="d-grid px-0">
                <Button onClick={createNFT} variant="primary" size="lg">
                  Create & List NFT!
                </Button>
              </div>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Create
```

I have tried to replace the link with an rpc node but really not sure